# Is one still a Muslim when he consciously disobeys a "law"?

Tags: sin, kufr

In the Quran much is written about what is wrong and what is right.

If a Muslim knows that something is wrong, and still does it (or that something is right and doesn't do it) - is he still considered a Muslim, or how strict does it get? What does the Quran say about it? What are the consequences?

Please try to get as much cites in your answer as possible! Thank you indeed!

I ask this question as for example in 5:51 it is written that one who takes Christians and Jews as allies (or friends) is one of them - and therefore not a Muslim anymore. And I wondered... wow this is pretty strict.
But I don't want to hear "no it's not that strict, don't take it that seriously" but the truth! How strict does it get and what does the Quran say about "just living the life" and just claiming to be a Muslim but not really caring what the Quran really says... or disobeying some things the Quran tells.

Comment: What makes one a Muslim is the Shahada and what makes one a Mu'min is the implementation of the tasks ordained by God in the correct manner. Alternately, if someone disobeys but still believes in the Shahada they are still a Muslim but have sinned and are accountable for their deeds on Judgement Day.  Normally it is kufr and shirk (Rejection of God or associating partners with Him like another God or Human or some kind of Amulet ) that takes you out of the fold of Islam. There are some things too but let's stay to the basics for now.

Comment: @Ahmed please read the answer and correct it if something is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, disobeying a law of Islam is not Kufr in itself. The evidence for this includes:

> إن تستغفر لهم سبعين مرة فلن يغفر الله لهم ذلك بأنهم كفروا بالله ورسوله
>
> If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times - never will Allah forgive them. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and His Messenger.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:80](http://quran.com/9/80)</sup>

> إن الله لا يغفر أن يشرك به ويغفر ما دون ذلك لمن يشاء ومن يشرك بالله فقد افترى إثما عظيما
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:48](http://quran.com/4/48)</sup>

Here Allah tells us that He might forgive any sin that is less than Kufr and Shirk, which proves that there exist sins that are not Kufr and Shirk. Since those sins are not Kufr, doing them does not make one a non-Muslim.

However disobeying some laws does make one a non-Muslim. This includes doing any action which explicitly implies disbelief or is the distinctive behavior of disbelievers. For example: uttering a statement professing disbelief in or disassociation from any agreed-upon teaching of Islam, prostrating towards an idol, insulting a Messenger, disrespecting a copy of the Quran, allying with non-Muslims in a war against the Muslims etc.

Comment: So one is only a muslim when he practises the five pillars and obeys to the laws. And if the muslim practises the five pillars, but doesn't study the quran (doesn't care much)? Because, if he doesn't know a law, he cannot follow it - and its therefore not considered to be a sin when he "disobeys" - as he doesn't know that it exists. If you know what I mean.

Comment: @watchme No. A person who believes in the obligation of the five pillars is a Muslim, even if he does not act on one of them out of laziness etc. If he denies their obligation he is a disbeliever. If he denies something in the Quran, he commits Kufr though he can repent and redo the Shahadah.

Comment: Which sin is less then Kufr?

Comment: Every sin that is not Kufr is less than it, adultery, theft, drinking wine, lying, backbiting etc. Provided that these are done because of temptation or weakness, while not denying that they are haram.

Comment: I just want to ask you again to get this right. If a muslim knows that something is wrong according to the quran, and still does it as he doesn't even really try to (but still believes that the quran is the one right book) - he is not a muslim anymore.